Any connection in the trivial line bundle is given by the exterior derivative $d: C^\infty(M) \to \Omega^1(M)$
I run into this statement: any connection in the trivial line bundle $\operatorname{pr}_M: M \times \mathbb{R} \to M$ is given by the exterior derivative $d: C^\infty(M) \to \Omega^1(M)$    with covariant derivative along $X$ being of the form $\nabla_X f = df(X) + f \omega(X)$ for any 1-form $\omega$ (particular case: $\nabla_X f = df(X) = X(f)$ is the flat connection).
How can I prove this or where can I find a proof? I checked Lee's book, but it looks like this is not there. Where did that $\omega$ come from? What they called a particular case, I thought it was the general case. In my GR course I was told covariant derivative of a function is simple differentiation
I have the following definition
Definition Let $\pi : E \to M$ be a smooth vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$. A connection in $E$ is a map $\nabla : \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E),$ $(X, Y) \mapsto \nabla_X Y,$ for which the three defining properties hold ($C^\infty(M)$-linearity in $X$, $\mathbb R$-linearity in $Y$ and the product rule)
I also know that the sections are $\Gamma(M \times \mathbb{R}) = C^\infty(M)$, other than that I have no idea how to procede.
Edit:



The claim is garbled. The correct statement is that for every connection on a trivial line bundle there is a 1-form $\omega$ such that the connection can be written as $d+\omega$.

The following two statements help to understand how one can describe all connections on a given vector bundle.
Proposition 1. Let $E$ be a smooth vector bundle, and let $\nabla^1, \nabla^2: \mathfrak X(M) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ be connections. Then their difference $D(X,Y) = \nabla^1_X Y - \nabla^2_X Y$ is a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping $\mathfrak X(M) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$. That is $D(fX,Y) = fD(X,Y) = D(X,fY)$ for any $f \in C^\infty(M)$. Conversely, if $\nabla$ is a connection and $D$ is a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping $D:\mathfrak X(M) \times \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$, then $\nabla + D$ is a connection.
Proposition 2. Let $E,F,G$ be vector bundles over $M$ and let $D:\Gamma(E)\times \Gamma(F) \rightarrow \Gamma(G)$ be a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping. Then $D$ is canonically induced by a section of the vector bundle $E^* \otimes F^* \otimes G$. In more simple words, $D$ comes from a smooth family of bilinear mappings $D_x:E_x \times F_x \rightarrow G_x$, $x \in M$ by virtue of the formula $D(X,Y)(x) = D_x(X(x), Y(x))$.
That is, if you want to describe all connections, you can start from constructing a single connection and then adding all possible ''difference tensors''.
In the concrete case $E = M \times \mathbb R$ we have a simple connection $\nabla^0_X f = df(X)$. Now, a difference tensor $D$ is a $C^\infty$-bilinear mapping $\mathfrak X(M) \times C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$. I claim that such mappings $D$ are in bijection with the space of $1$-forms $\Omega^1(M)$ via the correspondence $\omega \rightarrow D_\omega$, where $D_\omega(X,f) = f\omega(X)$. Indeed, it is clear that $D_\omega$ is $C^\infty$-bilinear. On the other hand given $D$ let $\omega_D \in \Omega^1(M)$ be defined by the condition $\omega_D(X) = D(X, 1)$. Clearly, we constructed the inverse mapping, so $\omega \rightarrow D_\omega$ is a bijection.
Edit. The connection $\nabla = \nabla^0 + D_\omega$ is flat if and only if $\omega$ is closed, i.e. $d\omega = 0$. We directly compute the curvature: $$\begin{split}\Theta_{\nabla}(X,Y)(f) = \nabla_X (\nabla_Y f) - \nabla_Y (\nabla_X f) - \nabla_{[X,Y]} f = \\ \nabla_X(df(Y) + f\omega(Y)) - \nabla_Y(df(X) + f\omega(X)) - df([X,Y]) - f\omega([X,Y]) = \\Y(f)\omega(X) - X(f) \omega(Y) + \nabla_X(f \omega(Y)) - \nabla_Y(f \omega(X)) - f \omega([X,Y]) = \\fd\omega(X, Y).\end{split}$$

How Do i get the formula $\nabla_X f = df(X) + f \omega(X)$? Can $\omega$ and $f $ be swapped here?

In the last paragraph of the answer I proved that arbitrary connection on a trivial bundle is of the form $\nabla_X f = df(X) + D_\omega(X,f)$ for some $\omega$. That is $\nabla_X f = df(X) + f\omega(X)$. $f$ and $\omega$ in the second term can be swapped since this term is $C^\infty$-bilinear, that is $f\omega(X) = \omega(fX)$.

Do you have a reference for the proof of those propositions?. How can we extend this definition to a connection in the trivial bundle $M × R^k$ of rank $k$?

and why for a flat connection $\omega=0$?

@some_math_guy I added flatness to the answer. For the reference I can recommend Lee's book on Riemannian manifolds Proposition 4.13 and Theorem 4.14. He does this for connections in tangent bundle, but the statements hold in general case with the same proof.

@some_math_guy for trivial bundle of rank $k$ the general form of a connection still can be found. It is basically the same, but now $\omega$ should be a $k \times k$ matrix of $1$-forms.

Where can I find a proof for the general case? I checked Lee's book (see images) and 4.14 is not even proved for the case of TM and it is not that straighforward as 4.13
